# If $\int_0^{u_n}\frac{e^t}{1+e^{-nt}}dt=1$, show: $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n(u_n-\ln2)=\frac{\ln2}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f_n:\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R$ be the function defined as follows:

$$f_n(x)=\int_0^x\frac{e^t}{1+e^{-nt}}\,dt,\qquad x\in\Bbb R^+$$

and let $u_n$ a sequence defined by  $f_n(u_n)=1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N,$ where $\Bbb N$ is the set of all natural numbers (positive integers).

I have already proved that $$\int_{0}^{u_n}\frac{e^{(1-n)t}}{1+e^{-nt}}\,dt =e^{u_n}-2$$ and $$e^{u_n}-2\leqslant\frac1ne^{u_n}$$ and $$\lim_{n\to \infty}n(e^{u_n}-2)=\ln2$$

please help me how to prove

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n(u_n-\ln2)=\frac{\ln2}{2}$$

Comment: Ana, you should add to your question what you have tried in order to prove that inequality, otherwise your question will be closed by moderators very soon.

Comment: Maybe also how you "already proved that..."

Comment: *Hint.* For $0\leq t\leq u_n$, $$\frac{e^t e^{-nt}}{1+e^{-nt}}\leq e^{u_n}e^{-nt}.$$

Comment: thanks for the help @SangchulLee

Comment: Since you already proved $e^{u_n}-2\le\frac{1}{n}e^{u_n}$, maybe you should update your title.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the limit you already proved:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}n(e^{u_n}-2)=\ln2,$$
let us prove the one for which you need help:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}n(u_n-\ln2)=\frac{\ln2}2.$$

---

From
$$e^{u_n-\ln2}=\frac{e^{u_n}}2=1+\frac{\ln2}{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right),$$
we derive
$$u_n-\ln2=\ln\left(1+\frac{\ln2}{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)=\frac{\ln2}{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right),$$
q.e.d.

Answer (score 2):

> $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}n(e^{u_n}-2)=\ln2$

From here, we can show $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}(e^{u_n}-2)=0\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}u_n=\ln2 $. Next, we have

$$n(e^{u_n}-2)=n(e^{u_n-\ln2+\ln2}-2)=2n(e^{u_n-\ln2}-1)$$

hence
$$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}n(e^{u_n-\ln2}-1)=\frac{\ln2}2$$
Then we get

$$\begin{align}\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}n(u_n-\ln(2))&=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}n(e^{u_n-\ln2}-1)\frac{u_n-\ln2}{(e^{u_n-\ln2}-1)}\\
\\
&=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}n(e^{u_n-\ln2}-1)\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{u_n-\ln2}{e^{u_n-\ln2}-1}\\
\\
&=\frac{\ln(2)}{2}\cdot 1\end{align}$$